# Considering conflict php5 for php7.3

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04

I recently switched from PHP 7.2 to 7.3 and when enabling it, I receive this message and I am not sure if it's an error or for informational purposes:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.3
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.3:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Enabling module mpm_prefork.
Considering conflict php5 for php7.3:
Enabling module php7.3.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
```

Do I need to do anything? It runs after restarting apache.

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: do you have solution?